# How to perform a quick turn in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe?

Tags: mario-kart-8-deluxe

I remember seeing somewhere that in Battle Mode there's a control to quickly "turn on the spot", but can't find the details anywhere. What button(s) do you press?

Comment: if you're referring to a 180° turn I didn't think there was one.  I also just tried every button on the controller in battle mode and didn't find one.  If you can find your source where you think you saw it I would definitely appreciate you linking it here.

Comment: I've been wracking my brain for where I read it but can't find it anywhere, Google fu failed me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this video:

You can perform a quick turn in Battle Mode by initiating a drift, then letting go of the gas button mid-drift.

But that's if you're already moving forward and need to turn around. If you need to quickly turn *from a (near) standstill*; hold the break and gas at the same time and steer in the desired direction. Your tires will squeal and your kart will turn on a dime. Release the brake to speed forward in whatever direction you are currently facing.

Comment: Awesome, handy to have the vid as well